# como selecionar um Array dentro de uma api no React?

Tags: json, array, node.js, react, axios

Fala pessoal? Tudo bem?

Estou com um problema em minha aplicação no React com uma api, vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Estou querendo mostrar os nomes dos pokemons de uma api, porém o array que fica os nomes dos pokemons fica dentro de "results" no "data" da api, ai sempre que eu tento executar o código da "undefined" como se não tivesse um array pra ele ler.

ainda não cheguei a colocar o render, porém como faço pra avisar o `this.setState({pokemon: response.data})` que o array esta dentro de results?

exemplo: `this.setState({pokemon: response.data"results"})`

```
import api from './api';


class App extends Component{

  state={
    pokemon: [],

  }

  async componentDidMount(){
      const response = await api.get('');
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({pokemon: response.data})
  }


  render(){};
}

export default App;
```

```
import axios from 'axios';


const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon'
})

export default api;
```

Comment: Tenta pegar assim: `response.data.results`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseando no seu texto, creio que o resultado de sua api vem assim:

```
results: [
  {id: 1, name: 'Nome1'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Nome2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Nome3'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Nome4'}
]
```

Então, no response do axios você pode obter os dados assim:

```
console.log(response.data.results);
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Funcionou, Valeu!!